# Colouring cells if last or first character is a space

Tags: excel, vba

Below is VBA code to color cells if the last character or first character is a space.

I tried a test file and it worked, but on the file that has to be checked, an error message appears:

> "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch".

If I click on debug, the yellow text line to show the error jumps to

`If Left(sheetArr(i, j), 1) = " " Then`

I checked my worksheet and the naming is correct.

I have thousands of cells to check. I may not modify cells, I may only add macros to check things because this file will be used by other departments.

```
Sub trailingspace()
'
' Find preceding and trailing spaces in a cell.
' Color these cells pink.
'

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim sheetArr As Variant
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("wording")
    sheetArr = sh.UsedRange
    rowC = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    colC = sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For i = 1 To rowC
        For j = 1 To colC
            If Left(sheetArr(i, j), 1) = " " Then
                sh.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 26
            End If

            If Right(sheetArr(i, j), 1) = " " Then
                sh.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 26
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: let's try: change `sheetArr(i, j) to sheetArr.cells(i,j) `. 
use `Or operator` to shorten the code.

Comment: Don't loop over all these cells. Either, look into conditional formatting OR use `ReplaceFormat`. Also, rather avoid `UsedRange` since it can return unwanted results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another alternative that avoids VBA entirely. I decided against using a formula that would include both leading and trailing spaces and separated out the rules just in case you (or someone looking at this question later) wanted a different format for each rule.

- Start by selecting the range you want to be checked for formatting.
- Create a new CF rule, selecting the 2nd option "Format only cells that contain".
- In the first dropdown box, select "Specific Text"
- In the 2nd box, select "beginning with"
- In the formula box, simply type a space
- Then select your desired formatting (which in your case, will be a pink fill)
- Repeat the steps above, except using "ending with" in this iteration

In the end, your result would look like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, I think this could be either a case for conditional formatting, or `ReplaceFormat` to prevent iteration over all these cells. Keep in mind `UsedRange` is unreliable too (and probably the cause of unreliable dimensions you calling your array with > yielding your error). So maybe try something like below:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, rng As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("wording")

    'Get last used row and column
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Set your range object
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, lc))

    'Set your ReplaceFormat
    With Application.ReplaceFormat
        .Clear
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 26
    End With

    'Replace formatting to cells with trailing and leading spaces
    rng.Replace What:=" *", Replacement:="", SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True
    rng.Replace What:="* ", Replacement:="", SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just apply a conditional formatting for the range you want to check using the following formula:

```
=OR(LEFT(A1,1)=" ",RIGHT(A1,1)=" ")
```

or add the condition using VBA

```
rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(LEFT(A1,1)="" "",RIGHT(A1,1)="" ""))"
rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With rng.FormatConditions(1)
    .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
    .Interior.TintAndShade = 0
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

Comment: From the VBA perspective, this would probably be my preferred solution as it incorporates conditional formatting. This means the code would not have to run every time a change has been made.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs. Do realize condtional formatting is volatile and **always** "runs" =). But yes, I agree. CF is a very nice alternative.

Comment: @JvdV but at least in can make use of multi-threading while VBA cannot :)

Comment: You are very correct, @JvdV! However, imagine placing OP's code into a worksheet change event!